# How can I disable Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook-messenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I log out of Facebook chat?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19100/how-can-i-log-out-of-facebook-chat)

Can Facebook chat be turned off? I don't like Facebook chat and want to disable it. I would like to have it always disabled and not have to disable it every time I sign on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on Chat

`Options` -> `Go Offline`

The next time you log in, it will remain offline.

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: @sidewaysmilk check the duplicate and see the year this was posted.

Comment: I read the date. The questions and answers stay up here permanently, so it's helpful to indicate that the accepted answer no longer works.