# How can I log out of Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook-messenger

About a week ago, Facebook was "upgraded" - don't know if it's a world wide issue - and the Facebook chat is **always** online. No matter I sign out.

How can I disable / completely sign out of Facebook chat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable facebook chat?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/how-can-i-disable-facebook-chat)

Comment: @Mehper The answer to that question is no longer valid. It refers to the old chat app.

Comment: @Alex: They can be merged or the other one should be deleted then (I'm flagging for deletion). The questions are the same, but Facebook is continuously changing.

Comment: I have closed the old question as a duplicate of this question as the information stated here is valid for the current version of Facebook. Thanks. [Discussion on Meta about this issue.](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/944/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions-with-different-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update:

1. Click on the "gear" icon in the right-upper corner of the chat window;
2. Click on **Turn off chat**.
   [image]

Or

1. Click on the "gear" icon in the right-upper corner of the chat window;
2. Click on **Advanced Settings...**;
   [image]
3. In the new window, click on **Turn off chat**;
4. Click **Save**.
   [image]

---

<del>1. Click on the "gear" icon in the right-bottom corner;</del>

<del>2. Click on **Available to Chat** to set it to disable.</del>

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get that setting to "stick"? In my experience, the flag gets enabled the next time I log in.

Comment: That's strange, but everything is strange with Facebook these days. In my case it sticks from session to session. It never gave me any problems.

Comment: I'll look at it again. It's conceivable it's a browser and/or browser extension issue.

Comment: Yeah I would check your browser. My Facebook Chat has not been enabled in months. @Al

Comment: thanks, you saved my day! Though this setting in new facebook is now in "Advanced settings".

Comment: This no longer persists. I get signed into Facebook Chat again and again. YMMV, but I've been enduring this for some months.

Comment: @sidewaysmilk It does for me; I keep it minimized and it persists from session to session. However, if I click on the minimized bar, it automatically gets turned on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I never touch that bar, and it always comes back. Lemme see...yep. Just reopened Facebook and I'm signed in again. @Joe's workaround works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I also have this problem, where Facebook keeps signing me back into chat after I go offline.

I found a reasonable, though not perfect, workaround:

Go to the "advanced settings" of the chat sidebar, choose the option "Only some friends see you...", and fill in one name only. Choose a person that you're OK with him/her seeing when you're online (I chose my wife :), and that way the rest of your Facebook friends will never see your online status, and you can remain signed in to chat.

Comment: Fantastic idea! I can't wait to see if it persists across sessions. Something tells me it will. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

2018 Facebook has changed things once again. There is no "Turn Off Chat" anymore, instead you need to "Turn Off Active Status". Steps are similar:

- Click on gear icon on Chat tab in bottom right (or Chat window on right if open)
  [image]
- Click on **Turn Off Active Status**
- Click on **Turn off active status for all contacts**

  - Alternatively you can choose to disable active status for just some contacts.
- Click **Okay**

After completing the above Chat tab in the lower right hand corner will be labeled "Chat (Off)".

Steps to turn it back on are similar:

- Click on gear icon on **Chat (Off)** tab in bottom right
- Click on **Turn On Active Status**

Answer (score 0):

I also updated my Facebook. Go to App Settings and there is an option there to sign off Facebook chat. It worked.