# How do I stay signed out of chat?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Whenever I turn off chat using the Facebook website, after a while, if I open Facebook again I'll be signed in to chat.

I should explain my setup. I have Windows 8 and a Windows Phone which are both connected to Facebook. In the Windows 8 Messenger app, I set my status to **Invisible** (the only other option is **Available**). On my phone I disabled the **Use Facebook Chat** setting.

After some minutes, when I visit the Facebook website I'll be signed back into chat, and on my PC my status will be **Available**. All this without me doing anything except for visiting the website.

The problem is I'm developing a Facebook app, and spend some odd hours working on it, so I don't want to be signed in all of the time.

For now I'm going with Joe's answer in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19100/how-can-i-log-out-of-facebook-chat), but neither of those answers are really solutions to the question (and I don't know how Joe's answer applies to the Messenger app).

How do I sign out of chat and get the settings to stick?