# Facebook shows me as online even if I turned off chat. How can I be offline in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy, chat, facebook-messenger

I never use Facebook Chat. It's always turned off. But I realized that it shows me as online (green dot) to my friends even if it's turned off.

Is there any way to be offline in Facebook? I don't want everybody to see when I login to Facebook. Why there's no option for that? What can I do? Is this is a bug or Facebook removed the ability to be offline completely?

This is not a duplicate of [How can I log out of Facebook chat?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19100/how-can-i-log-out-of-facebook-chat). It says “Turn off chat” on that question's answer but I say “I turned off chat but it still show me as online” — these are different issues.

Comment: Do you have any other devices connected to your facebook account (e.g. mobile phone, tablet, third-party apps)?

Comment: No, nothing. This started this week and I tested it enough and it seems it's a bug. Where can we report bugs for facebook? Damn Facebook how can they make such a mistake and don't fix it for days!

Comment: [Bugs & Known Issues - Facebook Chat](https://www.facebook.com/help/488113691204865) you can click the *please tell us more* to report a bug I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on comments I know that you don't have any other devices connected (which is a big first thing to check if others have this problem in the future). And you have tried the 'traditional' turn off chat:

> *This is not a duplicate of [How can I log out of Facebook chat?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19100/how-can-i-log-out-of-facebook-chat). It
> says “Turn off chat” on that question's answer but I say “I turned off
> chat but it still show me as online” — these are different issues.*

Based on other reports within Facebook it seems like many others are having this problem and that it is, indeed, a bug. However, a temporary workaround that can be successfully used is to manipulate the *Turn on chat option for only some friends* mode.

To [turn chat on for just some friends](https://www.facebook.com/help/130254323719420/)

> 1. Click gear in the chat sidebar
> 2. Select **Advanced Settings**
> 3. Click **Turn on chat for only some friends**
> 4. List the friends you want to turn on chat for

If you select just one friend to appear online for you should successfully appear offline for others.

As I mentioned in comments, [here is the link](https://www.facebook.com/help/488113691204865/) through which you can report a bug with facebook chat.

Comment: Has this bug been fixed now simply with turning chat off completely without leaving one friend being able to chat with you? Thanks.