# Why is Facebook telling people my last login time when I turned off chat for them?

Tags: facebook, chat

First of all, I have already seen [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45082/facebook-shows-me-as-online-even-if-i-turned-off-chat-how-can-i-be-offline-in-f), and my question is not a duplicate of that one.  In that question, the OP said he turned off his Facebook chat and his friends still see a green dot next to his name.  My problem isn't about the green dot.  Also, I have already tried [the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/45691/27367) to that question, and it doesn't solve my problem - in fact it *is* the problem.

My problem is that when I go to Facebook on a desktop PC and open up the "Advanced Chat Settings", it is set to "Turn on chat only for some friends" and I have only one friend in there (not my mother).  In addition, the chat bar on the right side shows my one friend, and then below that it says "These friends can't see you on chat" and shows all my other friends including my mother below it.  But I just noticed on my mother's Facebook, her chat window still shows my name along with the last login time (21h) and the mobile phone icon.

Why is Facebook showing my name in my mother's chat window along with my last login time?  My chat is supposed to be turned off for her, so shouldn't Facebook NOT tell her my last login time?

I thought this might have to do with the fact that there was a mobile icon next to my name in her Facebook chat.  I do have the Facebook app on my phone, but I just checked it, and when I press on that gear button in the upper right corner, it prompts me to "Turn On Chat" or "Cancel".  That tells me that chat is turned off in my Facebook app, so that can't be the reason for why my mother sees my last login time in her chat window.

So why is Facebook showing my last login time to my friends who are NOT on my "Turn on chat only for some friends" list?

Comment: If you're logging in from a Mobile device, I think it always shows your last login time, or that you're online from mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have tried everything now:

- I logged out of every Facebook app on my iPhone (the main Facebook app, the Facebook Messenger app, and the Facebook Camera app)
- I uninstalled every Facebook app on my iPhone
- I turned off chat for everyone in Facebook on my desktop PC

After doing all of those things and waiting over a week, my mother's Facebook chat window still shows my last login time.  It is impossible to not have Facebook tell all your friends when you last logged in.

Comment: Change your password and choose to log-off from all devices. And then do not login from mobile FB or messenger app. It will hide the login time.

Comment: I tried that and my mother's Facebook chat window still shows my last login time.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to find the answer to a similar question however I think I can answer yours. Even if chat is turned off on your mobile, your last login to facebook mobile will be shown to friends who you do not have chat open to, at least it shows them in the web chat sidebar. The only way around this I have figured is to uninstall or logout of the mobile app.

My question is whether the same thing happens for web. I have my chat only turned on for one friend and want to know if other friends see my last web login time in their chat sidebar. Facebook is deliberately anti-privacy!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your mobile app I went under my settings, then scroll down to "apps", then scroll down to "apps others use", then enable "if I'm online". That should remove your green online icon. I hope this helps.

Comment: My question isn't about the green dot.  Plus I completely uninstalled the mobile app, and Facebook still shows my last login time with the mobile phone icon.